# why is everything getting removed from my arraylist?

Tags: java, string, loops, arraylist, substring

I'm trying to answer this question:

> Program the method findIngredients. This method takes in a String called
>   foodInStock, and an ArrayList of Strings called ingredients. The method should return an
>   ArrayList of ingredients that were not found in foodInStock.

for example if:

```
foodInStock = “tomatopotatocornturkeycarrotstuffing”

ingredients = {“potato”, “corn”, “salt”, “chicken”, “turkey”}
```

returns {“salt”, “chicken”}

I tried writing some code but for some reason everything is getting removed when I use the above example on my program. Where did my program go wrong?

Here's my code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> findIngredients(String foodInStock, ArrayList<String> ingredients){
    ArrayList<String> ingredientsNotFound = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < ingredients.size(); i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < foodInStock.length()-(ingredients.get(i).length())+1; x++) {
            if (ingredients.get(i) == foodInStock.substring(x, (x + ingredients.get(i).length()))) {
                ingredients.remove(i);
                i = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    ingredients = ingredientsNotFound;
    return ingredientsNotFound;
}
```

Comment: You appear to be removing items directly from the parameter array lists, and so it should not surprise you that you're seeing this effect. Also, you're not adding anything to the ingredientsNotFound list, and so always returning an empty list.

Comment: You've also got a problem here: `if (ingredients.get(i) == foodInStock.substring(...` 
 Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods, on the other hand, check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: The way you run together the foodInStock items is very flawed. Suppose it contains the sequence "pineapple" and your ingredients includes "apple". Your algorithm would say that you have an apple in stock, which is not true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are two main things to cover here.

First, the way to build the final result. You are currently removing items from the original input; a better strategy is to add items to a new list (partially because it's simpler to think about and partially because you generally don't want to modify a list while iterating over it).

You also are, probably accidentally, overwriting your list with an empty list at the end.

Second, the way to determine whether or not the ingredient is in the string input. Rather than looping over the whole string and inspecting substrings, you can instead use the `indexOf()` method to see whether or not the string includes the current item.

```
public static ArrayList<String> findIngredients(String foodInStock, ArrayList<String> ingredients) {
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String ingredient : ingredients) {
        if (foodInStock.indexOf(ingredient) == -1) {
            results.add(ingredient);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Here we initialize a new list for the results. We then loop over every individual ingredient in the input list, and ask whether or not that ingredient is present in the string input. When it is not (`indexOf()` returns `-1`), we add it to the results list. At the end, the results contains every ingredient not found.